# Compare date with where clause

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$date=date("d/m/Y");
$d =  "select * from admission  WHERE batcht > $date";
$e = mysql_query($d);
while($f=mysql_fetch_array($e)){
echo $f[2];
}
```

I want to fetch the names where current date exceeds due date.it does'nt work. please help me

Comment: What is the type of db column (`batcht`)?

Comment: It is varchar containing all dates

Comment: First thing you need to check column data type (batcht) and second thing $date should be in single quots ('$date')

Comment: cast the `batcht` data to a date before the test - otherwise you are comparing two different datatypes

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` would help. But the format would be a problem. I would suggest to use `date` type if possible.

Comment: @ikbal can you please post a sample for your batcht value in the database ? i am not sure what you mean all dates ?

Comment: Thank you Sougata .... it works

Answer (score 1):

cast the date value in the varchar column `batcht` to a date before comparing with another date.

```
   select * from `admission`  WHERE date( `batcht` ) > str_to_date( '$date', '%Y/%m/%d' )
```

Thanks for the `headsup` @Sougata regarding date ~ didn't notice the invalid date format

Comment: `SELECT DATE('20/01/2016')` will return `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

The date in mySQL has this format: *'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'*.
So set *$date* liken this:

> $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s);
>   $d =  "select * from admission  WHERE batcht > '$date'";

...or, alternatively:

> $date = date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00';
>   $d =  "select * from admission  WHERE batcht > '$date'";

Comment: This wont help in this case.

Comment: Sure? Did you try it? (@Sougata)

Comment: There is a difference between dates & strings.

Answer (score 0):

**Database :** postgresql

If you want to check with date then not necessary to use php date function.

you can change in your query.

```
select * from admission  WHERE batcht > CURRENT_DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparision can only be performed in dates if and only if the datatype is been set to DATE or TIMESTAMP otherwise it will consider the value in db as a string and hence the results will be based on the length of string and not the data.

Hence I suggest you to please change the datatype of **batcht** column in the database

Answer (score 0):

For mysql you can use NOW() for current date time or alternatively CURDATE() for current date. So you query should be like this:

```
select * from admission  WHERE batcht > CURDATE()
```

And ditch $date variable since you don't need it now.